# Angular Parent Component property does not get updated when changing value from Child Component

Tags: angular, angular9

Below I don't understand why I'm getting the compilation error `Cannot use variable 'ft' as the left-hand side of an assignment expression. Template variables are read-only.`

If I remove the banana-syntax and leave it as [fileType], then I have no errors, but when I change the value from the Select control in the child component, the item in the parent collection fileTypes does not get updated. How should I do it so the parent collection gets updated ?

parent component

```
<app-file-type-list-item class="form-row align-items-end" *ngFor="let ft of fileTypes" [(fileType)]="ft"></app-file-type-list-item>
```

child component

```
<select name="fileType01" id="fileType01" [(ngModel)]="fileType" (change)="onFileTypeChange()">
 <option *ngFor="let fileType of fileTypes" [ngValue]="fileType">
       {{fileType.name}}</option>
</select>


export class FileTypeListItemComponent {


  @Input() public fileType: FileType;
 
  @Output() fileTypeChange = new EventEmitter();


  public fileTypes;

  constructor(private _entityManagerService: POPEntityManagerService) {
    this.fileTypes = // filled from datasource
    
  onFileTypeChange(): void {
    this.fileTypeChange.emit(this.fileType);
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I am using version 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using this syntax:

```html
<app-file-type-list-item class="form-row align-items-end" *ngFor="let ft of fileTypes; let i = index" [(fileType)]="fileTypes[i]"></app-file-type-list-item>
```

In case if it doesnt work plesase provide details for Angular compiler options in case these options are not enabled

```json
"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
"strictInjectionParameters": true
```

Comment: Yes, this syntax seems to work. No errors and the parent component collection gets updated. I can remove the `let ft of filetTypes` part I guess ?  I didn't know about this syntax, is this the "formal" way to do things ?

Comment: @Sam the things is that you've got a template variable same as component prop. If you read Angular Ivy compatibility guide you can see that its stated - "It is now an error to assign values to template-only variables like item in ngFor="let item of items" (previously, the compiler would ignore these assignments)." https://next.angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility

Comment: you are correct. I had no knowledge of that. I used to do this all over the place in my applications so this is a bit of a pain. Plus, I understand this is an evolution of Ivy, but it would have been good that the Angular team provides an "official" way to fix this error. I guess your way is fine, I just hope it is not breaking any angular principles

Comment: I know, they tried to change and generate better error for that but still. You can see the thread about that:
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/34339